# if i put a high polygons object far away, will it still slow my render time?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, dynamic-paint

i have a scene, where i need to use the dynamic paint to create waves. But the canvas has extremely  high polygon counts, and it would appear only on a fraction of the scene time. I tried baking the canvas and then remove the subdivide modifier to make it a plane, that doesn't work.
So i was thinking maybe i can put the object very far away from the scene, and hopefully it will not slow my render times. Will that work?

Comment: maybe you could even do a render then use it as an image in the background?

Comment: well the object ill be using is a bathtub, so it'll be kinda difficult won't it? to create an alpha especially if its inside the tub. Or am i wrong? i never used layer method before

Comment: Polygon count does not increase render times that much, at least if we're talking about a single object. You can use several alternatives to reduce the render times, but I think you're trying to optimize your scene a bit too early. I bet there are other things you can operate on that don't involve using workarounds to speed up your renders. eg reduce the light passes, compositing, etc.

Comment: @Gorgious it all depends... [Some](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeH4K.png) things are really subdivided so much it matters :D But to my knowledge this affects scene building, not each sample, so it matters most for rendering animations with few samples per frame.